# Multiple shops one shopping cart is not working

Tags: magento, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I have created in magento 2 shops with 1 common shopping cart. If I am a visitor and add to cart 1 product from 1st store and then go to 2nd store the cart reset.I saw on gap.com that this work. Anybody can help me with this problem?

Comment: Which shopping cart software does gap.com uses? Magento? Which edition?